# android.view.InflateException (Error inflating class) only on production

Tags: android, exception, crash, production-environment, production

My app uses a some 3rd party CustomView, which i didn't add it properly to the project.
What I did, i downloaded the files of the project as *.java and add them manually to the project under package com.blabla.utils.CustomView (this is how i defined it in the *.xml files that used this class).
When i was debugging/testing the app on multiple devices (using usb cable, and sending an signed apk to tester) , everything was seems to be ok.
But when i uploaded the app to production, I suddenly got exception

`java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.*.*}: 
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #55: Error inflating class 
com.*.*.CustomView`

Now, i realized what my problem was, I didn't add the project properly, 
I needed to add the library as an existing project into my workspace and them link this project to my main project.
And I changed the com.blabla.utils.CustomView to com.theoriginaldeveloper.package in *.xml files.
it did solve the problem  uploaded a new APK .

But my question is, why I didn't got this message while i was debugging the app? 
How can i be sure so avoid such exceptions on production?
What am I missing here?

(Notice : I did sign the APK with the same keystore which i used in testing and using Eclipse).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Likely, your release build was run through and obfuscator that mangled the class names while the debug builds were not obfuscated.

Android apps commonly use ProGuard as the obfuscator/optimizer.

Why it works with the original class names is because the library project has a proguard configuration file that contains rules to not obfuscate the particular classes because they need to be dynamically referenceable from XML layouts. When you changed the package name, the obfuscator rule didn't match the new package name.

Specifically, look for `proguard-project.txt` in the project directory and in there rules like

```
-keep public class foo.somepackage.SomeClassName
```

and make sure the rules are updated if you change package or class names.

Comment: as far as I understand he also signed and exported a package which he installed as a 3rd party application without issue.  Do you think that the ProGuard obfuscation could be affected when the application is published on the play store?